# this.state array in reactjs map is not a function

Tags: reactjs

```
import React from 'react';
import AppCard from './AppCard'
import FlatButton from 'material-ui/FlatButton'

export default class Column extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      cards: []
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h3>{this.props.name}</h3>
        <div>{this
            .state
            .cards
            .map(c => <AppCard>{c}</AppCard>)}</div>
        <FlatButton
          onClick={e => this.setState({
          cards: this
            .state
            .cards
            .push('asdf')
        })}>Add new card</FlatButton>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

pressing my FlatButton results in

Uncaught TypeError: this.state.cards.map is not a function at Column.render (Column.js:21)

Not sure what the underlying issue is since `cards` is definitely a map:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because of your push on this.state.cards.

Instead you might do :

```
<FlatButton
          onClick={e => this.setState({
          cards: [ ...this.state.cards, 'asdf']
        })}>Add new card</FlatButton>
```

This is because push is not returning the array you pushed, but the value you pushed.

So that your this.state.cards becomes 'asdf'

---

Or type the following to console, you ll get why this is happening.

```
var a = []
var b = a.push(1)
console.log(b) // logs 1 not [1]
```

Comment: thanks. when you dont touch js for a few months.. :--)

Answer (score 0):

The `.map` function is only available on `array`.
It looks like `cards` isn't in the format you are expecting it to be because when you push the `FlatButton` you set the state to a `Number`.

```
this.setState({cards: this.state.cards.push('asdf')});
```

this will set the cards to the value returned by the push function and that is a Number not an array.